# How to input only YYYY(Format year) in textbox using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="startYear"
                             placeholder="yyyy" min="1111" max="9999" />
```

I tried above way but didn't work

Comment: You can use moment library to accomplish this.

Comment: For now we need to accomplish this with lodash and angularjs

Comment: One way you can do is change the type from date to number this should work out for you and then you can watch the values for validation for some edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div date-input ng-model="date"></div>
```

Your directive template would look like this:

```
<input 
    id="exampleInput"
    type="number"  
    name="input" 
    ng-model="year"
    ng-change="setDate()"
    placeholder="yyyy" 
    min="1111" 
    max="9999"
/>
```

While your actual directive would look like:

```
.directive('dateInput', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      },
      templateUrl: './dateInput.html',
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.$watch('ngModel', function(nv, ov) {
          if (!angular.isDefined(nv) && !angular.isDefined(ov)) {
            scope.ngModel = new Date();
            scope.year = _getYear(scope.ngModel);
          } else {
            scope.ngModel = new Date(nv);
          }
        })

        angular.extend(scope, {
          setDate: setDate
        })

        function _getYear(date) {
          return parseInt($filter('date')(date, 'yyyy'));
        }

        function setDate() {
          var year = parseInt(scope.year),
              date = new Date(year, 1, 1);
          scope.ngModel = date;
        }
      }
    }
  }]);
```

So basic idea is to extract year from date input using angulars built in date filter or create new date object if value has not been passed and do the same thing.
Edit it and than compose a new date object and bind to ngModel.
You could easily do the same for month and day and replace 1 values that are passed to date object constructor.

Note that you also have to pass date formatted in a way Date object can read it.